# Include php file inside zip file

Tags: php, zip

I see in php.net and in this forum this for include files from zip file :

```
<?php
include ("zip://./test.zip#file.php");
?>
```

I create zip file called test.zip and inside put other file called file.php

The people say , this let include file.php inside zip file in other php file

I try all time and tell me error document no exists

```
Warning: include(zip://test.zip#file.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\AppServ\www\zip\zip.php on line 2

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'zip://test.zip#file.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\AppServ\www\zip\zip.php on line 2
```

The people tell this it´s right but for me , never works , i don´t know if i put something bad or need other thing

The Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

The following code works without any issues:

**page.php**

```
<?php
    include("zip://./include.zip#include_me.php");
?>
```

**include_me.php**

```
echo "File was included successfully!";
```

The issue you are encountering would suggest that there is an issue with the ZIP file itself. A common mistake to make is for the ZIP file to include a directory, and for all zipped files to be included within said directory.

I would recommend double-checking your ZIP file to ensure that just the file was zipped, and not the file and the directory.

If the directory has accidentally been included, your file might be located somewhere like `zip://./test.zip#test/file.php`

Comment: I create zip file in windows , and insert inside zip file other file in this case in php with a little code for read or include outside zip file , i do the same as you and give me error , inside zip file i have php file , include or try include and tell me the error i put up , i try in localhost in my computer server with Appserv , regards

Answer (score 0):

***Warning***: This cannot be done in memory — `ZipArchive` cannot work with "memory mapped files".

A note about the below, with power comes responsibility and it is up to each of us to ensure that no unfiltered user input ever ends up in eval().

You can obtain the data of a file inside a zip-file into a variable (memory) with [`file_get_contents`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) as it supports the [`zip://` Stream wrapper <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php):

```
$zipFile = './test.zip';     # path of zip-file
$fileInZip = 'file.php';    # name the file to obtain

# read the file's data:
$path = sprintf('zip://%s#%s', $zipFile, $fileInZip);
$fileData = file_get_contents($path);

eval($fileData);
```

You can only access local files with `zip://` or via ZipArchive. For that you can first copy the contents to a temporary file and work with it:

```
$zip = 'http://www.domain.com/test.zip';
$file = 'file.php';

$ext = pathinfo($zip, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$temp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $ext);
copy($zip, $temp);
$data = file_get_contents("zip://$temp#$file");
unlink($temp);

eval($data);
```

Or you can get this via stream with

```
$fp = $zip->getStream('file.php');
if(!$fp) exit("failed\n");

while (!feof($fp)) {
    $contents .= fread($fp, 1024);
}

fclose($fp);

eval($contents);
```

**PLEASE KEEP THE FOLLOWING IN MIND:**

*If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the
wrong question. -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP*

Comment: I try other time and no work me all time put me 
Warning: file_get_contents(zip://./test.zip#file.php) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\AppServ\www\zip\zip.php on line 13

Comment: Which one did you try